# Add cover image before image shows in gallery in magnific popup

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Couldn't figure out how to add a simple cover image into gallery items!

My code is as follows:

```
$j('.paintings').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
      enabled:true,
      tCounter: '<span class="mfp-counter">Paintings %curr% of %total%</span>' // markup of counter
    }
});
```

In .paintings div I have few images to display as gallery. Currently Gallery opens nicely and perfectly. But before the gallery images are opened I want to display a cover/splash image to tell user what kind of gallery they are going to view.

Not sure where to put that cover sample image in that code!

Any helps will be appreciate.

Comment: Live site: http://test.threebyfour.org/des/

Comment: It's not clear to me when/where is the cover/splash image supposed to show up. On hovering the thumbnails? After clicking the thumbnail but before loading the full image (and if so, each time or just once), something like the gray box currently does, or something before that even appears? And how/when does it go away? Ok, that's enough questions for now. :-)

Comment: Cover image will show up on popup before all images are shown. For example, i have 10 paintings images, if i click on any paintings thumbanil image before that image shown i want to show the cover image for few seconds. After few seconds then the actual paintings image will show.

Comment: So yes... After clicking the thumbnail but before loading the full image and yes each time